# Key pair stops working for SSH to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, key-pair

I created an AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu 20.04), and associated it with my key pair (that is already on AWS). Thus I could connect with SSH for several days. However, when I went to connect today, I get the message:

`ubuntu@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

I have checked everything, and the error persists. And this is not the first time this has happened. Ever since I started seriously using EC2 two months ago, this exact problem has happened several times. Usually the only solution is to save the instance as a template and re-create it again.

This seems very strange. Is this an AWS bug or what?

Comment: Give it a try by setting your key permission to 400. Does it work?

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-ssh-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: A stop/start doesn't have any effect either? Also, have you noticed any spike in CPU or RAM when this happens?

Comment: Might be a stupid thing but did you check you absolutely connect to the right instance? Also, did the IP address of the machine change in between?

Comment: You can obtain debugging information by using `ssh -vvv`. You can post the log in your question.

Comment: Weird, now it's working. I haven't changed anything, like permissions or anything. The exact same command, to the same IP, for the same user, now works, now that I returned from lunch and tried it again